# Requiring ActiveRecord on IRB - Ruby (NO Rails)

Tags: ruby, activerecord

How can I load `ActiveRecord` on an IRB session?

I have the following

```
# config/app.rb
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter:  'sqlite3',
  database: 'db/mydb.sqlite3'
)
```

But when I start IRB and try to load it

```
irb#1(main):001:0> require config/application.rb
```

I get

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object
Did you mean?  conf
```

I'd like to be able to interact with my ActiveRecord objects from IRB.
I'm NOT using Rails but only ActiveRecord.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two things to change here:

1. Always put quotes around the path you're requiring.  The reason Ruby is saying "undefined local variable or method" is that it's trying to interpret `config` as a variable name.  Put the name in quotes and it won't.
2. Use `require_relative` when loading files that are part of your application.  `require` only looks in the default Ruby load paths.

Try this:

```
    require_relative 'config/application.rb'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) to build a console started from command line. Simple console solution below. This way you don't have to require in irb every time you stare interactive session.

```
# bin/console
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require_relative '../config/app.rb'
require 'pry'
binding.pry
```

More about pry https://github.com/pry/pry

P.S. You should set +x on bin/console, i.e.

```
$ chmod +x bin/console
```

Then you just call

```
$ bin/console
```

and get all  the code run from config/app.rb and interactive session ready. No need to require anything from irb to start working.

Poor-man's rails console equiv. :-)